# In Swift, how do I create a convenience init for a class where the init's implementation creates the class value instead of calling an existing init

Tags: swift

I feel like the answer is obvious, but I haven't been able to figure this out and it seems to be a recurring problem for me. Basically I want to do something like this:

```
extension NSData {
    convenience init(JSONObject: AnyObject) {
        do {
            self = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(JSONObject, options: [])
        }
        catch {
            self = nil
        }
    }
}
```

However it won't let me simply assign a value to self. I do this all the time with enums, but it won't let me do it with classes. Is there any way implement at convenience initializer using an instance of the class created in the initializer implementation?

Comment: my understanding is self is immutable and convenience inits must use designated inits to make them work, you are creating a second instance inside your initial creation of an instance,  so that will not work.  Instead you are going to have to make an extension method that just returns your new instance

Comment: Ok thanks for the confirmation. I figured I'd have to end up just using a static method for rather than an init.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Saying that factory initializers are *"not supported **yet**"* in Swift is fallacious. Their exclusion is a design decision, and their use intended to be covered by *failable initializers*; quoting [the following Apple Swift blog post](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17)

> Failable initializers eliminate the most common reason for factory
>   methods in Swift, which were previously the only way to report failure
>   when constructing this object.
>
> ...
>
> Using the failable initializer allows greater use of Swift’s uniform
>   construction syntax, which simplifies the language **by eliminating
>   the confusion and duplication between initializers and factory
>   methods**.

So in your case, you're probably looking for a convenience failable initializer. E.g., something along the lines

```
extension NSData {
    convenience init?(JSONObject: AnyObject) {
        do {
            let foo = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(JSONObject, options: [])
            self.init(data: foo)
        }
        catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

/* Example usage */
let foo : AnyObject = ["Foo":"bar"]
let bar = NSData.init(JSONObject: foo)
```

---

In the title of your question you include *"... instead of calling an existing init"*. When making use of `convenience` initializer, a designated initializer (of same class) must be called at some point (even via other convenience initializers). From the [Swift Language Guide - Initialization - Class Inheritance and Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html):

> ...
>
> **Rule 2**
>
> A convenience initializer must call another initializer from the same
>   class.
>
> **Rule 3**
>
> A convenience initializer must ultimately call a designated
>   initializer.

The example code above, however, allows an early escape (failure) of the convenience initializer if `NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(...)` fails, but if it succeeds, sooner or later a designated initializer needs to be called (in this case `init(data:)` designated initializer).

---

For details on failable initializers, see the [Swift Language Guide - Initialization - Failable Initializers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html). For an additional remark regarding the initializer chain (`convenience -> ... -> designated initializer`), see rickster:s comment below.

Comment: You left out Rule 1 of initializer club: Don't talk about initializer club. Er, wait. Really, to add one bit to a great post: all of this chaining business is key to the initializer model in Swift, because it ensures both that no instance "escapes" initialization without all of its state attended to, and that no throwaway instances are created/discarded during initialization (which is what happens when you wrap a `+objectWithXYZ` factory in an `-initWithPDQ` initializer in ObjC).

Comment: @rickster Thanks for the feedback and the additional inititializer club insights.

Comment: This answers my question. Basically I wanted to know if you can initialize a class by assigning self like you can with structs, enums, and other value types. It looks you can't. The reason makes sense. I just wish each class had a built-in copy constructor so you could implement convenience initializers by supplying a instance of the class, created by some other library, into the copy constructor. This would satisfy the init chaining rules while having flexibility in how you implement the convenience inits. Looking at the above example, NSData has a copy constructor(init),but most classes dont

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you want a factory initializer. In Swift they are not supported yet. The best you could do is to use static factory method.